# load texture from user upload to geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

### I'm new to three.js and javascript (coding in general) but I'm having a lot of fun experimenting with the possibilities and have created a few small Three.js scenes with lights, custom geometry from 3D JSON models to develop my skills to be able to tackle my ultimate goal of building a 3D website.

I'm currently entirely stuck on the issue of allowing a user to upload an image file from an HTML 'input' file tag, and have that image appear on a PlaneGeometry mesh that already exists in the scene with a dummy texture already loaded into the material.

I can have the texture image appear on the plane without issue, and I have the HTML 'input' file button appearing onscreen, I can click it and it will load an image but it's not linked to anything in three.js and that's where I get stuck, I don't understand how to proceed.

I found this [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uJqbJ/4/) that I can see works but I can't figure out how to use it to add a custom texture to a geometry and material that already exist.

```
<body>
<!-- three.js container -->
<input id="userImage" type="file" />
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = vec4(uv * 2. - vec2(1, 1), 0., 1.);
    }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
    precision highp float;

    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D texture1;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv.xy);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script>

    init()

    function init(){
        $("#userImage").change(function () {
            var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
            var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );
            image.onload = function()  {
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
        };

        userImage = $("#userImage")[0];
        if (userImage.files && userImage.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image.src = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(userImage.files[0]);
        }

        camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera();
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: false
        });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
            uniforms: {
                texture1: {
                    type: "t",
                    value: texture
                }
            }
        });
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1), shader));

        $('#container').append(renderer.domElement);

            animate();

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    }); 
    }
</script>
```

### Would anyone mind sharing an example of how they would go about allowing a user uploaded texture to be loaded onto an already existing texture, material and object??

[image of current three.js result with HTML loader at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmrff.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a "change" event
to the "file" `input`:

```
document.getElementById('userImage').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
     .....  
} );
```

The new file can be get by the `target.files[0]` property of the event argument:

```
var userImage = e.target.files[0];
```

Use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a DOMString containing a URL:

```
var userImageURL = URL.createObjectURL( userImage );
```

I recommend to use [`THREE.TextureLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) for loading a texture:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin("");
var texture = loader.load(userImageURL);
```

See the example, which is based on the code of your question:

```js
init()
  
function init(){
    document.getElementById('userImage').addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    var userImage = e.target.files[0];     
    var userImageURL = URL.createObjectURL( userImage );

    container = document.getElementById('container');      
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");
    var texture = loader.load(userImageURL);

    shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
        uniforms: {
            texture1: { type: "t", value: texture }
        }
    });
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1), shader));

    animate();
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    } ); 
}
```

```html
<input id="userImage" type="file" />
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = vec4(uv * 2. - vec2(1, 1), 0., 1.);
    }
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
    precision highp float;

    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D texture1;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv.xy);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rabbid! Your example really helped me understand how to load the initial scene after I'd chosen the texture from the 'userImage', that's working great!!!

You used the example code to add another domElement to the window, but I'm after how to replace the texture in the existing scene and have the scene update so any objects that share the previous texture (clone tex) also have their texture change.

I've tried looking into clearing the entire scene (which i couldn't figure out how), but I'd like to be able to change the textures in a non-destructive way, by loading in the new image.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
shader.uniforms.texture1.value = texture
```

That would go inside of the file onChange method, and it essentially replaces the initial texture with the uploaded texture.

Like so:

```
fileUpload(e) {
    let userImage = e.target.files[0];     
    let userImageURL = URL.createObjectURL( userImage );

    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");
    let texture = loader.load(userImageURL);

    // update texture
    shader.uniforms.texture1.value = texture;
}
```

Run that `fileUpload` method with the input onChange. That way, you don't need to re-init the scene every time an image is uploaded.

Make sure `shader` is a variable which can be accessed from within the `fileUpload` method.